# Which tripod mount do I need?

Tags: tripod-socket

I bought a Canon DSLR in Singapore in 2005 and recently lost my tripod.

I am vaguely aware that tripod mounts are either metric or imperial. Which am I likely to need?

Comment: "I am vaguely aware that tripod mounts are either metric or imperial." No, they're almost universally Imperial (more specifically, UNC) - even when every other nut/bolt/socket/stud on the same piece of equipment *is* metric.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All Canon DSLR's (in fact, probably all DSLR's and mirrorless cameras from any brand for decades till today) use a standard 1/4" 20 pitch thread. In other words, any decent tripod will do the job.

You will find that any tripod, whether $20 or $500 will fit your camera.

Comment: Most point-and-shoot cameras are 1/4"-20 as well.  It's really only cell phones that don't use the standard tripod thread.

Comment: I'm not up on all the latest cell phones, but I've yet to see one with a tripod mount built in. All the various tripod mounts I've seen that are designed to grip a phone come with a 1/4-20 tripod thread.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia - Tripod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripod_(photography)) screw threads are...

> Per ISO 1222:2010, the current tripod bolt thread standard for attaching the camera calls for a 1/4-20 UNC or 3/8-16 UNC thread. Most consumer cameras are fitted with 1/4-20 UNC threads. Larger, professional cameras and lenses may be fitted with 3/8-16 UNC threads, plus a removable 1/4-20 UNC adapter, allowing them to be mounted on a tripod using either standard.

I have no idea what any of those numbers actually mean, but they look like Imperial sizes to me. UNC seems to be American  ;)

In practical terms, you could safely walk into a camera shop & pick up any tripod they have on sale.
Over the past 30 years I've had three cameras & two tripods & never even considered the screw thread. They all 'just fit, as if by magic…' or convention.

Comment: Even German cameras made before WWII used 3/8-16 or 1/4-20.  And yes, those are US Customary sizes.  American cameras have those sizes going back to the 1880s.

Comment: A parallel from the recording industry… Microphone stands have one of two size threads. No-one ever seems to know what the technical sizes are, but you can get a 'big thread to little thread' adaptor anywhere that sells mics or stands. Mic clips often come with a free insert adapter. The 'little thread' fits lighting equipment too. The small screw-on aluminium 'hats' that lights can be clamped to are 'little thread'. I found this out by accident when I started photography - I've pressed a couple of huge orchestral boom mic stands & several smaller ones into service as light stands.

Comment: They're probably 1/4-20 and 3/8-16 as well, since most of that technology was from the USA and pre-metric England too.

Comment: @ZeissIkon -  You can't screw a camera onto either. 'small thread' is already too big for a consumer camera [might fit the bigger pro, I cannot tell] but 'large thread' fits nothing else I've ever seen. I imagine there is common ground somewhere, but I don't have enough choices of equipment to fully test the theory. Pic to follow...

Comment: Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHPW.jpg - Left to right, mic stand with mic adapter; mic stand with lighting 'hat'; tripod with consumer thread as per above. Not my finest work, just tried to lean some stands up where they wouldn't fall over. For those seriously into their vintage audio, they're leaning on an 80's Teac 32-2B tape recorder. If that whets your appetite, on top of it sits a very rare Revox B77 ASC Version, tantalisingly out of shot ;)))

Comment: The two sound equipment threads I can see both look like 3/8-16.  Might just as easily be M8 or M10, though; a lot of Japanese influence there for stuff made after WWII.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - I found https://www.musicalhow.com/microphone-stand-thread-sizes/ - my brass mic adapters inner thread is dual sized, from each end, smallest fits my mic stands, largest fits nothing I own.

Comment: Yes.  Aside from the 1/4-20 and 3/8-16 aspect, there are a couple of things to watch out for if you start customising fittings: One is that all or most of the other screws in a head or bracket are likely to be metric - Manfrotto label some of them on some products.  The other is that there are two different 1/4-20 threads: UNC and BSW (Whitworth).  The latter was the standard on cameras for many years. They're pretty much compatible but an old tripod can be a bit of a loose fit in a new camera, and a new tripod tight in an old camera. (60° thread angle in UNC and a 55° angle in BSW)

Comment: And the dimensions are *nominal* diameter (1/4 or 3/8"), i.e. the diameter the male thread would be if it wasn't truncated, which it is, and turns per inch (-20 or -16)

Comment: The Unified Thread Standard was adopted by the Screw Thread Standardization Committees of Canada, the United Kingdom, and the United States in 1949. Includes Unified Coarse (UNC), Unified Fine (UNF), Unified Extra Fine (UNEF) and Unified Special (UNS). Not long after metric started eclipsing inch based standards.

Comment: @Tetsujin [apparently](https://www.musicalhow.com/microphone-stand-thread-sizes/) 3/8-16 is used but of the common threads in microphone stands 1/2-12 is the smaller and 5/8-27 is the larger.  The latter will look really fine and the former quite coarse

Answer (score 5):

As other answers note, almost all modern tripods have 1/4-20 male thread to mount and secure the camera.  The only significant exception to this is the various proprietary quick-release mounts, most of which don't interchange between brands.  Even with these, the plate on the camera attaches with the same standard thread to the camera's tripod socket.

If your camera has a threaded socket in the bottom, rather than some kind of plate, you don't need to match quick release mounts.  You just need a standard tripod with 1/4-20 screw on top.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the quick-release mounts are after attaching one piece to the camera, but the thread itself is the same.

Comment: You're correct -- if there's a plate on the camera, it should also have a thumbscrew or similar underneath to mount and dismount it.

Comment: Is a 2015 Canon DSLR "modern" enough ?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica "Modern" in this context means anything since the mid-1950s.  I have a 1955 Kiev 2 with a 3/8 socket, but it's an exact copy of a 1936 or so Contax, and the next model (Kiev 4) had 1/4-20.  Most every other hand holdable camera had 1/4-20 socket by 1955 or so.